# Right aligning pagenumbers in index with imakeindex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indexing, imakeidx

I am trying to right align the pagenumbers in my index. I use `imakeidx` and tried to use a custome index style file (`.ist`). I would like to keep the two column layout of `imakeidx`. I tried using `\hfill` as delimiter however this seems to yield always the same width of gap.

How do I rightalign the page numbers while keeping the two column layout?

`index.ist`-file:

```
delim_0 "\\hfil"
delim_1 "\\hfil"
delim_2 "\\hfil"
```

mwe:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s ./index]
\begin{document}
Indexing\index{what!index} some\index{some} demonstrative\index{demonstrative} entires.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\hfill` and not `\hfil`

Comment: To expand on egreg's comment, paraphrasing Knuth (p.71) "you can think of it as if `\hfil` has one mile of stretchability, while `\hfill` has a trillion miles."  If an `\hfill` exists in the underlying code, it will prevent your `\hfil`s from stretching.  That is why you have to fight `\hfill`s with `\hfill`s.

Comment: if there are just one or two page numbers per index entry, then `\hfill` should do the job.  but if there are lots of numbers for an entry, such that more than one line is required, then extra measures will have to be taken.  see the texbook, appendix d, pp.392-394 for a rather extreme case (the *math. reviews* "key index").  it would look even nicer with hanging punctuation, but it was quite enough of a problem in 1980 to get this to work reliably; this was one of the problems i took with me to stanford when i went there to learn tex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\hfil` is not working.

Please try this `ist` file:

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\hfill"
delim_2 "\\hfill"
```

`\dotfill` (for better reading fills the line with dots, `\hfill` has no dots, but the numer is right justified.

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to right align the page numbers when I have multiple lines of page numbers?

Comment: @bmv – depending precisely what you want, you may find that `\usepackage{imakeidx}` `\usepackage{etoolbox}` `\patchcmd\theindex{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}{}{}` does this.